# Create a variable to hold objects of different types C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, object, variable-declaration

I have 3 different objects `A`, `B` and `C`. Depending on the the parameter given, I would like to choose among these different objects. In programming,

```
class A { 
  public: 
    void printHello() { cout << "HELLO A" << endl; }
}; 

class B { 
  public: 
    void printHello() { cout << "HELLO B" << endl; }  
};

class C { 
   public: 
     void printHello() { cout << "HELLO C" << endl; }  
}; 

int main () { 
    string key = "c"; 
    A a; 
    B b; 
    C c; 
    Object obj; // I don't know how to declare Object. 

    if (key == "a") obj = a; 
    else if (key == "b") obj = b; 
    else obj = c;
    obj.printHello(); // print Hello C.
    return 0; 
}
```

I have thought about templates and struct objects. But none of them work so far.

```
template<typename T1, T2, T3> 
T1 getType(string key, T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3) { // this is problem coz return types are different.
    if (key == "a") return t1; 
    else if (key == "b") return t2; 
    else return t3; 
}
```

It is easy to create `Object o;` in `JAVA` because every object in Java is subclass of `Object` class. But how do I achieve this in C++?

Edit.
I can't change class `A`, `B` and `C`. I was given these classes to work with and my goal is to implement `main` method. So, `inheritance` was out of the question for me. Sorry for any confusion.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a case for inheritance?

Comment: In Java every class implicitly inherits from `Object`. You can simulate the same thing in C++ by writing an abstract class `Object` yourself.

Comment: Take a look at [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Comment: You don't need an `Object` class that everything inherits from. You just need your own base class that all *your* classes inherit from.

Comment: You don't even need to couple your types with a base class. A variant is the perfect solution for this case.

Comment: @JesperJuhl std::any is C++17. I have some backward compatibility issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for a `variant` type. There's an upcoming `std::variant` in C++17, and C++11-compliant versions in `boost` and around the web. Example with [**`boost::variant`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
struct visitor
{
    void operator()(const A&){ cout << "HELLO A" << endl; }
    void operator()(const B&){ cout << "HELLO B" << endl; }
    void operator()(const C&){ cout << "HELLO C" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    visitor v;

    // `obj` is either an `A`, a `B` or a `C` at any given moment.
    boost::variant<A, B, C> obj{B{}};
    //                         ^^^^^
    //                   Initialize with `B`.

    boost::apply_visitor(v, obj); // prints "HELLO B"

    obj = A{};
    boost::apply_visitor(v, obj); // prints "HELLO A"
}
```

Comment: Good answer to the question as phrased... But it is pretty obvious that the OP would be better served by learning about inheritance

Comment: @Nemo Ehm, no, not clear at all. Maybe for some other use case that actually called for inheritance.

Comment: This looks like the answer I was looking for. Let me try that out first and accept it as answer.

Comment: @pseudo: great to hear that. If you're interested in variants and similar concepts you should check out [Ben Deane's "Using types effectively" talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojZbFIQSdl8). I've also written [a few articles about "variant visitation with lambdas"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/variants_lambdas_part_1.html).

Comment: Nearly 7 years later ... The variant looks interesting, however, a more generic solution IS one using a base class. Consider the case when there are more than just three classes. A project I'm working currently has more than 500 classes that subclass/extend "Vendor". Being Java, we can just drop in new classes at runtime and it all works; using a variant would require coding/testing/deployment of the entire application.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you should use a virtual common base class/struct and a pointer to this base class/struct.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
 { virtual void printHello () = 0; };

class A : public Base { 
  public: 
    void printHello() { std::cout << "HELLO A" << std::endl; }
}; 

class B  : public Base{ 
  public: 
    void printHello() { std::cout << "HELLO B" << std::endl; }  
};

class C  : public Base{ 
   public: 
     void printHello() { std::cout << "HELLO C" << std::endl; }  
}; 

int main () { 
    std::string key = "c"; 
    A a; 
    B b; 
    C c; 
    Base * obj; 

    if (key == "a") obj = &a; 
    else if (key == "b") obj = &b; 
    else obj = &c;
    obj->printHello(); // print Hello C.
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If the OP knows all the types in advance, then `virtual` is suboptimal compared to variant: it can have negative performance implications and also forces the interface of all the types to be the same. Also, you should mark `printHello` as `override`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - you're right; unfortunately `std::variant` is available only starting from C++17 (but good point the use of `boost::variant`); anyway... maybe I'm wrong... but seems to me that the OP don't known C++ as known Java and should understand how to use virtual inheritance

Answer (score -4):

you could do something like

```
if (key == "a") obj=new A();
else if (key == "b")  obj=new B();
```

Comment: That would work if 'obj' was a pointer to an instance of the base class, but in the question there is no relationship between the 3 classes except they implement the same function.

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual original question, can you improve on this? Thanks